# WCF call keeps running

Tags: c#, wcf

I am banging my head after enormous search. A very strange thing i am facing after adding some fields in my model. The wcf service was working perfectly before, now its call keeps the browser spinner rotating and the call doesn't end.

I have written a wcf wrapper on my Business logic objects. Business object works perfectly and even the BO call also returns the object but i think response formater face some issues.

Below is the WCF declaration and the Business object call in implementation.

> Declaration

```
    [OperationContract]
    [WebGet(UriTemplate = "GetUserProfile?UserID={UserID}&LoggedInUserID={LoggedInUserID}",
    ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml)]
    UserProfileEntity GetUserProfile(long UserID, long LoggedInUserID);
```

> Implementation

```
    public UserProfileEntity GetUserProfile(long UserID, long LoggedInUserID)
    {
        using (UserProfileBO prof = new UserProfileBO())
        {
            return prof.GetUserProfile(UserID, LoggedInUserID);
        }
    }
```

I debug the code and it works fine till even dispose of `UserProfileBO`. But browser keeps spinning even after execution of last brace.

Where can i get to know about any potential error.

Thanks in advance

**EDIT**

Strange is when i return the incomplete entity, it works fine. In my `UserProfileEntity` i have complex type `SysUser` in which i added the nvarchar Field. if i assign this object in my resultant entity, it breaks.

Comment: what is the client side code that you are invoking to the services? post the full code of that operation. Also have you pulled up the network monitor/activity/trace in your browser to see if there is a request pending or being sent when you say "it keeps spinning"?

Comment: my client is android and iphone but for testing i just put url (Myservice.svc?GetUserProfile?UserID=48482&LoggedInUserID=48482) in browser and it keeps spinning

Comment: have you seen the requests/responses go through/come back through the development tool bar in your browser? is it truly waiting or...something else?

Comment: in fact my mobile developer asked me that the request is not coming back after latest updates, then i tried the url on browser and it keeps loading, Let me check in developer tool

Comment: The error is 'Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FAILED'

Comment: oh sorry the error i mentioned is of default google page, when i loaded about:blank it didn't show that error, when i entered the url its keep loading :(

Comment: Do you get any exceptions on the server side at all? did you check the event viewer or enable WCF Tracing?